# Replace character at a given position in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace

Let us say I have a string of 16k characters which may contain a comma(,) at many positions 
but I want to replace the commas(,) at the position 4001,8001,12001 only with null

There may be commas(,) at other positions for example 4002 which shouldn't be replaced.

Sample data below

```
        WITH data
         AS (SELECT To_clob(Lpad('A', 4000, '0'))
                    ||To_clob(Lpad('A', 4000, '0'))
                    ||To_clob(Lpad('A', 4000, '0'))
                    ||To_clob(Lpad('A', 4000, '0'))
                    ||To_clob(Lpad('A', 4000, '0')) AS file_data
             FROM   dual),
         data1
         AS (SELECT LEVEL
                    lvl
                    ,
                    Substr(file_data, Decode(LEVEL, 1, LEVEL,
                                                    ( ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 4000 ) + 1),
                    4000)
                       file_data,
                    1
                       order1
             FROM   data
             CONNECT BY ( ( LEVEL - 1 ) * 4000 ) + 4000 <= Length(file_data))
    SELECT Wm_concat(To_clob(file_data)) file_data
    FROM   data1;
```

Comment: Replace with what? And where - in a table? Only in the output of a query? Then - is it guaranteed that the input is 16k characters, and there are commas at positions 4001, 8001, 12001 - or do those have to be checked first?

Comment: replace with null only in the output of the query ,there is no gaurantee that the input is 16k and there are commas at every multiples of 4000+1 positions

Comment: `wm_concat` was never documented (and therefore supported), and on my version, 12.2, it is not recognized. However, if it does work for you, here is a possible approach: chunk the input into 4000 character pieces; then, for each piece, compute `nullif(substr(piece, 1, 1), ',') || substr(piece, 2)`; and then call `wm_concat` on these results.

Comment: on a generic query how to remove character say comma from a specific location where there an other commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEX_REPLACE` to replace characters at certain position.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE('This,is,mystring,with,16kchars,imtrying,toreplace,comma,at30th,position','(^.{30})(.{1})(.*)$','\1\3') 
FROM dual;
```

Output.

```
 This,is,mystring,with,16kcharsimtrying,toreplace,comma,at30th,position
```

*You can change your position accordingly. But this is not specific to comma. It replaces anything with at the given position*

Comment: What if I want to replace ;  with null and also ; with comma

Comment: If you want to replace comma with `;` instead of null,  change the last part to `'\1;\3'`